# update_batch and insert in codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have two tables . the first one is customer and the second one is customer_tel.
each customer can have one or more tel_number so i store customer's number in customer_tel. my problem is about updating the customer_tel . i do not know how many tel_numbers can customer be having. so if a customer has already a tel_number and now wants to edit it or add new tel_number how i can use update and insert together ?
for example the customer table is :

```
id = 1 , fullname : john doe
```

and the customer_tel is :

```
id = 1 , customer_id = 1 , tel_number = 123456789
id = 2 , customer_id = 1 , tel_number = 123456
```

each user can edit or add their tel_number .  i am familiar with update_batch but in here it can not work because i have insert too in the same time .
my solution is delete the rows that have customer_id = 1 and insert_batch the new data . is there any way better than this?

```
        for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($_POST['tel_title']) ; $i++){
        $tel[] = array(
         'customer_id'=> $id,
         'tel_title'=> htmlspecialchars($_POST['tel_title'][$i]),
         'tel' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['tel'][$i])
        );
    }
    $this->base_model->delete_data('customer_tel' , array('customer_id'=> $id));
    $res = $this->base_model->insert_batch('customer_tel' , $tel);
```

Comment: I personally would do the delete all and re-insert like you suggest. The only extra check is you wrap it in a Transaction to make sure the whole process completes. You wouldn't want the user to loose all their details but have their main record updated.

Comment: how can i put it in Transaction?

Comment: Please see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$this->db->delete('customer_tel' , array('customer_id'=> $id));
$res = $this->db->insert_batch('customer_tel' , $tel);
```

instead of

```
$this->base_model->delete_data('customer_tel' , array('customer_id'=> $id));
$res = $this->base_model->insert_batch('customer_tel' , $tel);
```

Comment: i know that. my methods are in base_model.php :))

Comment: The attributes of `customer_tel` are `id`,`customer_id` and `tel_number` as you have mentioned. But in `for loop`, you are using `customer_id`,`tel_title` and `tel`. Please cross check them.